# Migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.2 and now I want to auto migrate to AndroidX using from `Redactor`->`Migrate to AndroidX` and now it has this error:

> Android dependency 'androidx.media:media' has different version for
>   the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should
>   manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably one of your dependencies uses `androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc1`. You should use [Gradle's Dependency Resolution Strategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) to force all dependencies to use the same version.
Try to add the following code in your app level `build.gradle` and it should work.
Something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
       // Your code
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
       // Your build types if any
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use this command to detect which of your dependencies uses `androidx.media:media`:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

Comment: I had the same issue for this dependency "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4" and add both of them to "resolutionStrategy" and fixed my problem.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Where do we exactly add this strategy in app level or project level build.gradle?

Comment: @HardikTrivedi You should add it to the app level gradle file at the root of your configuration. I'd say right before `dependencies` declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Refactoring will change old imports to following:

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

You may want to use following instead if you do not plan to use legacy dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

This will remove the issue as well if you are not using media at all...

Comment: Removing `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix it manually.

Just change dependency to:

> androidx.media:media:1.0.0

And change **imports** in your classes

Comment: I don't use "androidx.media:media" at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and i resolved it by using :

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.3.0' // Old 1.2.71
    ...
}
```

Endly i changed gradle version from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
...
```

I hope this will help.